# Where do the directors who didn't go to film school actually learn filmmaking?

Tags: production, directors

For directors who didn't go to film school, where did they learn filmmaking? Watching movies and making short films give you a experience, of course. But it's usually not enough to be a professional director.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Movies & TV S.E.! Your question is a little vague and you might want to add some details to it (who are you talking about, where did you hear about these people or their background, etc). Also, this community aims at discussing films and series and mostly works of fiction rather than the lives of people who make them, so I'm not sure it's the best fit for this site.

Answer (score 7):

Many of the generation of the original Star Wars trilogy learned largely by watching "making of" videos and using Super 8 and newly introduced consumer video cameras to hone their craft.  [Kevin Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Smith) is a member of this generation, and has said he was inspired to become a filmmaker after seeing [Richard Linklater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Linklater#Early_life)'s [Slacker](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102943/?ref_=fn_al_tt_4) and recognizing you could make a feature film with next to no budget. Linklater, who is about ten years older, reportedly taught himself simply by making Super 8 movies in his youth.  [Peter Jackson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Jackson) also just started making movies in his youth, and eventually saved enough money to switch to 16 mm, on which many of his early, cult classics were shot.

Quentin Tarantino seems to have attained mastery of the craft by watching every movie he possibly could, probably thinking about them obsessively, and then writing 2 great screenplays which were made into films by other directors ([True Romance](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108399/) and [Natural Born Killers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110632/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)) before he wrote a screenplay with a low enough budget ([Reservoir Dogs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105236/?ref_=nv_sr_1)) for him to be able to direct.  [Note that he had co-written and directed a prior, "amateur" film [My Best Friend's Birthday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Best_Friend%27s_Birthday) which was partially destroyed in a lab fire and never released.]

Woody Allen started out as a professional comedy writer in television before making the transition to film.  In his case, he likely pitched the studios until he got greenlighted on his first project [What's Up, Tiger Lily?](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061177/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_53) Because he was already well regarded in the industry, he could get meetings.

[François Truffaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Truffaut#Career) began as a brutal film critic. It's possible he was spurred to start making film because of his dissatisfaction with the state of contemporary cinema, much as playwright [Anton Chekov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton_Chekhov) felt compelled to expand from criticism to dramatic writing per his angst over the inadequacy of melodrama and romanticism. (Both artist were pioneers in important artistic movements.) As with everyone else here mentioned, he just began directing, first with a short films, and eventually with feature length work.

These are just a few examples.  The details are going to be unique for each individual self-taught filmmaker.

Comment: Don't forget actors. Tons of actors start directing projects.

Comment: @Catija Very good point!